# How do I make a file reader in python from a file spec?

Tags: python, file-io

OK I'm fairly new at working with files in general, does anyone have a tutorial that will show me how take the information from a file spec so I can manipulate the file in python. I want to learn how to do this in general for the future, but specifically the format I'm interested in now is call sff and is basically type of archive that contains pcx images with some information about each frame, The end goal is I want to unpack it and turn subgroups of the pcx's into animated gifs(I already can do the last part, I'm just trying to figure out how to unpack the sff right now). I've tried to piece together information about reading binary files from the python docs, and using seek read and struck unpack, but it doesn't seem to work like I'm expecting it to. Right now I'm stuck at `seek(24)` `read(4)` (That is supposed to give the location of the next subheader), and getting the result of `\x00\x02\x00\x00` . which I guess is hex(but I don't know how to get python to tell me that). So I'm looking for a tutorial, but specific answers are welcome too. Thanks.

Here is the spec I have:

```
/*--| SFF file structure
|--------------------------------------------------*\
Version 1.01
HEADER (512 bytes)
------
Bytes

00-11 "ElecbyteSpr\0" signature  [12]

12-15 1 verhi, 1 verlo, 1 verlo2, 1 verlo3   [04]

16-19 Number of groups   [04]

20-24 Number of images   [04]

24-27 File offset where first subfile is located     [04]

28-31 Size of subheader in bytes     [04]

32 Palette type (1=SPRPALTYPE_SHARED or 0=SPRPALTYPE_INDIV) [01]

33-35 Blank; set to zero     [03]

36-511 Blank; can be used for comments   [476]

SUBFILEHEADER (32 bytes)

-------

Bytes

00-03 File offset where next subfile in the "linked list" is    [04]

located. Null if last subfile

04-07 Subfile length (not including header)  [04]

Length is 0 if it is a linked sprite

08-09 Image axis X coordinate    [02]

10-11 Image axis Y coordinate    [02]

12-13 Group number   [02]

14-15 Image number (in the group)    [02]

16-17 Index of previous copy of sprite (linked sprites only)    [02]
This is the actual

18 True if palette is same as previous image     [01]

19-31 Blank; can be used for comments    [14]

32- PCX graphic data. If palette data is available, it is the last

768 bytes.
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: That hex number is 0x00000200 or 512 in decimal. The function call `struct.unpack('I', '\x00\x02\x00\x00')` gives the correct answer.

Comment: @Blair thanks, I tried the struck.unpack but I had missunderstood the part about using the I. This works for me now.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home).